# is Drools 6.5 integration with Spring framework deprecated?

Tags: java, spring, drools

I am unable to use spring and drools integration as in the xml i get a validation error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
     http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring              classpath:org/kie/spring/kie-spring-6.0.0.xsd">
```

or when using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
     http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring              http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd">
```

I have the spring drools integration jar in path: (which internally contains the xsd at org/kie/spring/kie-spring-6.0.0.xsd)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${kie.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

However i do not see this xml at http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd
Any idea abt how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you test version 6.5.0.Final of Drools? I was able to integrate Drools with Spring Boot but, honnestly, the configuration took me a little effort as well.

Please find following additonal tips:

1) The only dependency I needed is the following:

```
<!-- Drules Rules Engine -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
    <version>${kie.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Please read tutorial https://scattercode.co.uk/2015/02/06/a-minimal-spring-boot-drools-web-service/ Apart from the kmodule.xml and a rules file, you don't need any additional configuration.

3) I created my RuleService and kieContainer the following way:

```
@Service
public class AdDecisionEngineRuleService {

    @Autowired
    public AdDecisionEngineRuleService() {
        LOGGER.info(">>>Initialising our KieContainer.");
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        kieContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
    }
```

Ping me again if you would be stuck still or please vote for my answer if this was helpful.